# Why restTemplate.put() throws "HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found"

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate, rest-client

I make a put request

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.put(new URI("http://localhost:8080/test"), dto);
```

which successfully hits the rest endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public void test123(@RequestBody DTO dto) {
    System.out.println("phone:"+dto.getPhone()); 
}
```

but the "put" method on the client throws exception, even though the server is hit successfully and I don't 
expect return value.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:589)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:547)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.put(RestTemplate.java:394)
    at com.my.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

Comment: are you able to hit URL - http://localhost:8080/test from browser ?

Comment: Could you include whole @Controller source?

Comment: I can't hit it from browser: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: I found the problem, it turns out I am missing @ResponseBody on test123(). I mislead you by posting the question with the annotation present, actually I was missing it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is super old, but another fix is to add a @ResponseStatus annotation onto the controller and specify HttpStatus.NoContent as the value. This way you are accurately returning a status and don't have to say that nothing (void) is a response body.